# An example of a non trivial weakly compact in $L^1$

Tags: measure-theory, banach-spaces, compactness, uniform-integrability

Let us consider the space $L^1$ of measurable functions associated to a probability space. I would like to see non trivial examples of  weakly-compact sets.

Thank you.

Comment: In light of the Dunford-Pettis theorem you are really just asking about interesting examples of weakly closed, [uniformly integrable](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1259009/why-did-mathematicians-introduce-the-concept-of-uniform-continuity/1259106#1259106) families.  Adding the tag.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $g\in L^1$ non-negative and consider
$$
K:= \{f \in L^1 : |f| \leq g\}
$$
Then $K$ is bounded by $\|g\|_1$ and uniformly integrable (by the absolute continuity of $\int g$), and so it is weakly compact by the Dunford-Pettis theorem. (See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability))

Edit: As pointed out by Norbert, it remains to show that $K$ is weakly closed. Since it is convex, it suffices to show that it is strongly closed. However, if $(f_n) \subset K$ with $f_n \to f$ in $L^1$, then there is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ which converges pointwise to $f$. From this it follows that $|f| \leq g$ holds as well.

Comment: You need to show that $K$ is weakly closed.