# Is uniform continuity related to the rate of change of the function?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question, intuition, uniform-continuity

I have been trying to understand how uniformly continuous functions differ from functions that are continuous but not uniformly continuous. Based on some examples and counter-examples, my feeling is that uniformly continuous functions cannot change "rapidly". Hopefully, the following examples will make it clear what I mean by that:

1. $f(x) = 1/x$ is **not** uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ because it "blows up" at $0$, that is, its slope becomes infinite very quickly. Similar functions would be $\log x$ on $(0,1)$ and $\tan x$ on $(0,\pi/2)$.
2. $f(x) = x^2$ is **not** uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$ because it goes to infinity "rapidly" in the sense that the function's rate of change is greater than that of linear functions, for sufficiently large $x$.
3. $f(x) = x^{1/3}$ **is** uniformly continuous on $(-1,1)$, because even though the slope does become infinite at $0$, it does not happen "rapidly" as in the previous two examples.
4. $f(x) = \sin (1/x)$ is **not** uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ because it oscillates "rapidly" as $x$ approaches $0$.
5. $f(x) = x\sin(1/x)$ **is** uniformly continuous on $(-1,1)$ because, although the frequency of oscillation remains the same, the amplitude is "small enough" to make the function uniformly continuous; in some sense, the function is not changing rapidly enough for it to fail to be uniformly continuous.

This is admittedly a very naive way of looking at uniform continuity, but does it have any merit? Is there a way to describe uniform continuity by rigorously formulating the notion of rate of change of the function?

Some difficulties I already see are:

1. There are continuous functions that are not differentiable, so the natural idea of rate of change is not applicable to them.
2. There even exist continuous but nowhere differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$, and we know that any continuous function on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous. So, the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) restricted to $[0,1]$ is a uniformly continuous function. Surely, the function changes "rapidly" all over the place, but somehow it doesn't do so "rapidly enough"?

I have tagged this as a soft question because I know there is a lot of ambiguity in this post. It would be very helpful if anyone can give me insights about why this method of thinking of uniformly continuous functions (at least in the real one-variable case) can or cannot be fruitful.

Also, this is a related post that I found useful, especially the most upvoted answer: [Why did mathematicians introduce the concept of uniform continuity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1259009/279515)

Comment: For example 5 you should say that $f(x)=x\sin 1/x$ for $x\ne 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Your understanding of the topic is insightful and not naive.  The derivative $f'(x)$ is  the limit of the change of $f$ in proportion to the change in  $x$, as the change in $x$ approaches $0,$ so it is a "local" property. But uniform continuity of $f $ is a "global" property. The W. function changes at a rapid rate, but it is not that it doesn't change rapidly enough.  The intervals( in the domain) of rapid _rates_ of change are short, similar to  the intervals in which the derivative of $x\sin 1/x$ is large

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thank you for the encouragement. It is interesting that the derivative (or rate of change) is a local property, whereas uniform continuity is a global property; this did not occur to me at all. I will ponder over what you said about the Weierstrass function. It will be nice to be able to pin down exactly how the intervals of rapid rates of change are short enough to make it uniformly continuous.

Comment: If $J$ is a closed bounded subset of $\Bbb R$ then any continuous $f:J\to \Bbb R$ is uniformly continuous on $J.$.... There exists a continuous periodic $f:\Bbb R \to [0,1]$ with period $1$, such that for any $x\in \Bbb R$ and any $r>0$ we have (i) $\sup \{|\frac {f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}|: 0<|y-x|<r\}=\infty,$ and (ii) the cardinal of $\{y\in (-r+x,r+x): f(y)=f(x)\}$  is the cardinal of $\Bbb R.$...  It was a surprise when Weierstrass first exhibited a continuous nowhere-differentiable function.

Comment: There is also something called absolutely continuous, which is stronger than uniformly continuous. See Wikipedia. I dk much about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does, in the following sense: for a function $f$ to fail to be uniformly continuous, there has to be a pair of infinitely close points such that the difference in values of $f$ at those points is *appreciable* (hence not infinitesimal).  That's a tremendous rate of change and you don't even need to require the function to be differentiable for this to work.

Answer (score 5):

Rates of change without differentiability is indeed a problem. What you can measure, in a sense, is average rates of change. You can still define the average rate of change of $f$ over $[a, b]$ to be
$$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}.$$
Note that there's no differentiability required here.

When $f$ is a Lipschitz-continuous function (stronger than uniform continuity), this is always bounded, regardless of the choice of $a$ and $b$ (in fact, this is the definition of being Lipschitz-continuous).

When $f$ is uniformly continuous, the situation is a little more subtle. It's not helpful to consider the single numerical value $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$, but instead view the largest possible allowance for $f(b) - f(a)$ as a function of the length of the interval, $b - a$. With a Lipschitz-continuous function, halving the largest allowable value of $f(b) - f(a)$ corresponds to halving the length $b - a$, but this isn't the case with a general uniformly continuous function. Instead, we have that $f(b) - f(a)$ tends to $0$, at some (possibly non-linear) rate as $b - a$ tends to $0$, regardless of the values that $a$ and $b$ actually take.

Let's take an example: $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Note that $f$ is not Lipschitz-continuous, as
$$\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a} = \frac{\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a}}{b - a} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a}},$$
and taking $b$ and $a$ arbitrarily small makes this value tend to $\infty$. However, if we fix $\varepsilon > 0$, we can force $|f(b) - f(a)| < \varepsilon$ by making $b - a$ small, regardless of the values of $a$ and $b$. That is, $f$ is uniformly continuous. To see this, first suppose $b - a < \varepsilon^2$. Then
$$b < \varepsilon^2 + a \le \varepsilon^2 + 2\sqrt{a}\varepsilon + a = (\varepsilon + \sqrt{a})^2,$$
hence $\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a} < \varepsilon$. So, it's not a linear function of $\varepsilon$, but by forcing $b - a < \varepsilon^2$, we are forcing $f(b) - f(a)$ to be smaller than $\varepsilon$.

By taking smaller and smaller intervals, we can still have $\frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b - a}$ to be larger and larger, but when we fix $b - a$ to be at least some minimal length, we can make $f(b) - f(a)$ small.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. You've explained the meaning behind the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of uniform continuity in terms of average rates of change being controlled sufficiently tightly. I think my understanding of this would improve by considering what happens when we apply the same analysis to a continuous function which is not uniformly continuous. It is not immediately clear to me how from your answer how the rapid rates of change are controlled well. I shall get back to you on this in a while.

Comment: Well, in short, for a general continuous function, you cannot bound $f(b) - f(a)$ just by controlling $b - a$. You need to also control where $a$ (or $b$) is. That is, we could make equally small intervals at various points along the domain, but $|f(b) - f(a)|$ cannot necessarily be made uniformly small on all of them. Take $f(x) = x^2$ as an example. If we force $b - a = \delta$, we can still make $f(b) - f(a)$ arbitrarily large. But, by fixing $a$, we can force $\delta$-close points to map to $\varepsilon$-close points to $f(a)$. So, $f$ is continuous, not uniformly continuous.