# What is difference in approaches between using standard part in NSA and limit?

Tags: integration, nonstandard-analysis, infinitesimals

What is difference in approaches between using standard part in NSA and limit? I don't mean technique of differentiation or integration.

Can somebody explain it on example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In NSA, the concept of limit is defined in terms of the standard part.  Thus, to calculate the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ tends to $0$, one would perform two steps: (1) evaluate $f$ at an infinitesimal value $x=\alpha$, and (2) take the standard part.  The limit exists if and only if the standard part exists for all infinitesimal $\alpha$, and furthermore they all have the same value.

Comment: Is there case when finding limit is more difficult than finding standard part?

Comment: Working with limits in non-infinitesimal calculus (using the epsilon-delta definitions) is generally more difficult than working with standard part in infinitesimal calculus.  For example, I've had a graduate student (!) tell me that he did not properly understand the notion of *uniform continuity* until he saw a definition of this notion via infinitesimals (which is simpler than the epsilontic definition).

Comment: @MikhailKatz Though I am not _that_ graduate student, I thought I could let you know that [your short answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2739769) to [Is uniform continuity related to the rate of change of the function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2729618) was very useful to me when I has asked the question (as a graduate student). :)