# Uniform continuity of $\sqrt{x}, x\in (0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

In the lecture, lecturer said that $\sqrt{x} ,\,x \in (0,1)$ is uniformly continuous. But, I think it is not uniformly continuous because as $x$ approaches to 0, we require to have smaller $\delta$ for a given $\varepsilon$.

I have not learnt proper proof of uniform continuity, yet. If i am wrong, please explain to me..

Thanks,

Comment: Perhaps you may be interested in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249552/what-is-the-geometrical-difference-between-continuity-and-uniform-continuity/1249643#1249643) and the other answers in that thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The definition of uniform continuity is, to recall that a function $f \colon [0,1] \to \def\R{\mathbf R}\R$ is *uniformly contiuous* iff 
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0\; \exists \delta > 0\; \forall x,y \in [0,1]:\; |x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(y)| < \epsilon $$
So let $\epsilon > 0$ be given, recall that for $x,y \in [0,1]$ we have
\begin{align*}
  |\sqrt x - \sqrt y|^2 &\le |\sqrt x - \sqrt y|\cdot |\sqrt x + \sqrt y|\\
   & = |x-y|\\
 \iff |\sqrt x - \sqrt y| &\le |x-y|^{1/2} 
\end{align*}
That is, we can choose $\delta := \epsilon^2$ and everything works fine.

Another possibility is to use the compactness of $[0,1]$ and recall that every continuous function is uniformly continuous on compact sets.

Answer (score 1):

It's uniformly continuous because it is continuous on $[0,1]$. Given an $\epsilon>0$, you choose a $\delta$ for continuity at $0$! and then that $\delta$ works for the  uniform continuity definition, too.