# Is there a short method to detect uniform continuity.

Tags: calculus

I was wondering is there a very short trick  to find weather a given function is uniformly continuous or not without using epsilon and delta definition.Can someone give me a graphical insight of uniform continuity?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249552/what-is-the-geometrical-difference-between-continuity-and-uniform-continuity/1249643#1249643

Comment: Thanks Sir.
By I wanted to know is there a quick method to guess uniform continuity?

Comment: If the domain is not compact, check for a bounded derivative

Answer (score 1):

The most important principle is the following:

An  elementary function ("analytical expression" in $x^k$, $\sqrt{\mathstrut}$, $\exp$, $\cos$, etc.) is *continuous* on its full domain of definition, i.e., the set $\Omega$ of points where it can be evaluated without asking questions.

Such a function is then *uniformly continuous* on any compact subset of $\Omega$.